# How does gcc search framework headers on Mac OSX(10.15)?

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

By `gcc -v` I know that gcc searches in these paths:

```
/usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include
 /usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

I write:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
int main() {
        return 0;
}
```

It gives no error messages. But with the following, gcc cannot find the header.

```
#include <CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h>
int main() {
        return 0;
}
```

I know that gcc finds the header CoreFoundation.h in `/System/Library/Frameworks`. And the path of the header is `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h`.

My question is: why `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>` is OK? Why not `CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h` (it gives error messages)? I think it should be `CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h`, as the full path of the header is `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h`, and the inlcude path is `/System/Library/Frameworks`.

Thanks in advance.

The following may have something to do with this problem.

I compile a file that include 'CoreServices/CoreServices.h'.

```
did not find header 'CoreServices.h' in framework 'CoreServices' (loaded from '/System/Library/Frameworks')
```

Then I use `gcc -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/`, because I know the header's path is `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h`. But it still doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two lines in the `gcc -v` output is a hint about special directories that are handled not like include directories.

```text
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

Apple's gcc for Darwing architecture has special extensions for finding include files from framworks. You can read about the [Darwin Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Darwin-Options.html)

Especially look at -Fdir option. It allows to specify other framework dirs additional to the listed above. This option describes how gcc looks for header files in a framework:

> A framework directory is a directory with frameworks in it. A framework is a directory with a `Headers` and/or `PrivateHeaders` directory contained directly in it that ends in `.framework`. The name of a framework is the name of this directory excluding the `.framework`. Headers associated with the framework are found in one of those two directories, with `Headers` being searched first. A subframework is a framework directory that is in a framework’s `Frameworks` directory. Includes of subframework headers can only appear in a header of a framework that contains the subframework, or in a sibling subframework header. Two subframeworks are siblings if they occur in the same framework. A subframework should not have the same name as a framework; a warning is issued if this is violated. Currently a subframework cannot have subframeworks; in the future, the mechanism may be extended to support this. The standard frameworks can be found in `/System/Library/Frameworks` and `/Library/Frameworks`. **An example include looks like `#include <Framework/header.h>`, where `Framework` denotes the name of the framework and `header.h` is found in the `PrivateHeaders` or `Headers` directory.**